# alignment of buttons using Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Trying to create a window using `Tkinter` and arrange the buttons in the grid, but the alignment wasn't coming as expected.

The assignment given to me is to create a window like this

[image]

but my out put was something like this

! [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtYPW.png)

the code was totally similar to the answer given, but I don't know what's wrong of my code:

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title("Password Manager")
window.config(padx=20, pady=20)

canvas = Canvas(width=200, height=200)
img = PhotoImage(file="logo.png")
canvas.create_image(100, 100, image=img)
canvas.grid(column=1, row=0)

# website input

label_web = Label(text="Website:")
label_web.grid(column=0, row=1)

web = Entry(width=35)
web.grid(column=1, columnspan=2, row=1)
# mail input
label_mail = Label(text="Email/Username:")
label_mail.grid(column=0, row=2)

mail = Entry(width=35)
mail.grid(column=1, columnspan=2, row=2)

# pass input
label_pass = Label(text="Password:")
label_pass.grid(column=0, row=3)

password = Entry(width=21)
password.grid(column=1, row=3)

# add butt
add_butt = Button(text="Add", width=35)
add_butt.grid(column=1, columnspan=2,row=4)

# generate butt
generate_butt = Button(text="Generate Password")
generate_butt.grid(column=2, row=3)

window.mainloop()
```

I want the exact alignment.

Comment: Please post the code as text, not a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost done.

```
canvas.grid(column=1, row=0)
```

With

```
canvas.grid(column=1, row=0, columnspan=3)
```

and

```
password = Entry(width=21)
```

```
password = Entry(width=18)
```

You can see the result you want by simply modifying it with.

But in this way, the more complex the widget placement becomes, the more difficult the placement becomes. If you use tkinter's Frame widget, placement can be a little easier, so it would be good to learn about Frame.

Answer (score 0):

> I want the exact alignment.

You must create window object for every widgets.

Add `columnspan=3` for `canvas`, `web`, `mail` and `add_butt`.

Add `columnspan=1` for password and `columnspan=2` for `generate_butt`.

Avoid wildcard `from tkinter import *`

Snippet:

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Password Manager")
window.config(padx=20, pady=20)

canvas = tk.Canvas(width=200, height=200)
img = tk.PhotoImage(file="logo.png")
canvas.create_image(100, 100, image=img )
canvas.grid(column=1, row=0, columnspan=3)
 

# website input

label_web = tk.Label(window,text="Website:")
label_web.grid(column=0, row=1)

web = tk.Entry(width=35)
web.grid(column=1, row=1, columnspan=3 )
# mail input
label_mail = tk.Label(window,text="Email/Username:")
label_mail.grid(column=0, row=2)

mail = tk.Entry(width=35)
mail.grid(column=1, row=2, columnspan=3)

# pass input
label_pass = tk.Label(window,text="Password:")
label_pass.grid(column=0, row=3)

password = tk.Entry(window, width=16)
password.grid(column=1, row=3, columnspan=1)

# generate butt
generate_butt = tk.Button(window,text="Generate Password")
generate_butt.grid(column=2, row=3, columnspan=2)

# add butt
add_butt = tk.Button(window,text="Add", width=30)
add_butt.grid(column=1, row=4, pady=10, columnspan=3)
  
window.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]