# How can I shift this password entry box to a bit aligned with others?

Tags: python, tkinter

So I am making this program as a part of this course and I can't really happen to figure out what to do with the password entry box.

```
from tkinter import *
window=Tk()

window.title("Password Manager")
window.config(padx=20,pady=20)

canvas=Canvas(height=200, width=200)
logo_img=PhotoImage(file="logo.png")
canvas.create_image(100, 100,image=logo_img)  #If we don't give x and y, it will give error
canvas.grid(column=1, row=0)



#Creating Website
website_label=Label(text="Website:")
website_label.grid(row=1,column=0)
website_entry=Entry(width=35)
website_entry.grid(column=1, row=1,columnspan=2)

#Creating Email/Username
email_label=Label(text="Email/Username:")
email_label.grid(row=2,column=0)
email_entry=Entry(width=35)
email_entry.grid(column=1, row=2,columnspan=2)

#Creating Password
password_label=Label(text="Password:")
password_label.grid(row=3,column=0)
password_entry=Entry(width=21)
password_entry.grid(column=1, row=3)

#Adding Buttons
generate_password_button=Button(text="Generate Password")
generate_password_button.grid(column=2, row=3)
add_button=Button(text="Add",width=36)
add_button.grid(column=1, row=4,columnspan=2)


window.mainloop()
```

[What I am getting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArlUE.png)
This password field should just be aligned with other at start position, can't put a clear photo of expected result.

Comment: Add `sticky="w"` to `.grid(...)` on all the entry widgets.

Comment: Does this help my answer  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76792346/alignment-of-buttons-using-tkinter/76793795#76793795

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are using explicit **width** for your widgets. This approach will slightly change your widget position.
You can do that but then you need to configure where the widget should stick. Another thing is that I recommend further dividing of frames, so you will have more control over it.

One possible solution would be:

```
from tkinter import *
window=Tk()

window.title("Password Manager")
window.config(padx=20,pady=20)

canvas=Canvas(height=200, width=200)
logo_img=PhotoImage(file="logo.png")
canvas.create_image(100, 100,image=logo_img)  #If we don't give x and y, it will give error
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0)

#dividing up frames
fr_main = Frame(window)
fr_main.grid(row=1, column=0)

#Creating Website
website_label=Label(fr_main, text="Website:")
website_label.grid(row=0,column=0)
website_entry=Entry(fr_main, width=35)
website_entry.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="we")

#Creating Email/Username
email_label=Label(fr_main, text="Email/Username:")
email_label.grid(row=2, column=0)
email_entry=Entry(fr_main, width=35)
email_entry.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky="we")

#Creating Password
password_label=Label(fr_main, text="Password:")
password_label.grid(row=3, column=0)
#group widget in frame for more control
fr_passw = Frame(fr_main)
fr_passw.grid(row=3, column=1)
password_entry=Entry(fr_passw, width=21)
password_entry.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w")
generate_password_button=Button(fr_passw, text="Generate Password")
generate_password_button.grid(row=0, column=1)

#Adding Buttons
add_button=Button(fr_main, text="Add",width=36)
add_button.grid(column=1, row=4, sticky="we")

window.mainloop()
```

So that way you don't need to deal with column span!